# Save state of MovieClips and Buttons to File.

Tags: actionscript-3, file, flash, save

Is there any way to save the objects that are currently on the stage in Flash?

For example, if the user drags a particular `MovieClip` from a panel that is part of the interface and places it somewhere on the stage and then adds a `TextField` by clicking a `Button`.

Is there any way to save the location, properties and various other things to an external file?

So that, if the user were to click a 'load' button, it would load the `MovieClip` and text back onto the blank stage when the program is next run and they'd be in the exact same position?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can save this information in XML file for example.

Sample of XML might be like so,

`WorkSpace.xml`

```
<stageObjects>
    <object libName="myTextField" type="TextField" xPos="20" yPos"10" txt="SomeText" />
    <object libName="myMovieClip" type="MovieClip" xPos="20" yPos"10" />
</stageObjects>
```

On your app load, read this XML file and take the required actions.

Comment: Right, I see. My app basically consists of `Buttons` that add `Movieclips` to the stage upon being clicked. I also have a button that creates a `TextField` as well as a `ColorPicker` to change the text color. Can I set the `xPos` and `yPos` to take the x and y values for the object from the stage?

Comment: Keep recording every action in XML file. Before that you make a first cut of your XML structure for various operations and actions you might perform in your app.

Comment: Do you know if there is any useful documentations or examples of this in practice that would assist me?

Answer (score 0):

If I had any type of local client-level game and I was using flash to save local values for the same purposes a cookie may have; I would utilize the [SharedObject Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html). It is not a traditional mime type, it also has a .sfo extension and they are usually stored in a random directory..So they are only cleared when the user Flushes their "Regular" Browsing Data. Without getting overly complicated, this demo will allow you to save data, close the SWF file, re-open it and find the last setting.

> package {
>
> > import flash.display...
> >        import flash.events...
> >        import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
> >        import flash.net.SharedObject;
> >        import flash.net.SharedObjectFlushStatus;
> >        import flash.text.TextField;
> >        import flash.text...
> >       
> >      public class SharedObjectClass {
> >
> > > ```
> > >    private var _so:SharedObject; 
> > >    private var _in:TextField = new TextField(); 
> > >    public function SharedObjectClass() { 
> > >        _so = SharedObject.getLocal("application-name");
> > >        addChild(_in.text = String(_so.data.savedValue));
> > >    }
> > >    private function saveValue(event:*=null):void {
> > >        _so.data.savedValue = _in.text;
> > >        var flushStatus:String = null;
> > >        try {
> > >            flushStatus = _so.flush(10000);
> > >        } catch (error:Error) 
> > >            //..nothing?
> > >        }
> > > ```
>
> ```
>        if(flushStatus != null) {
>            if(flushStatus == SharedObjectFlushStatus.PENDING) {
>                _so.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onFlushStatus);
>            }
>        }
>    }
>
>    private function clearValue(event:*=null):void {
>        delete _so.data.savedValue;
>    }
>
>    private function onFlushStatus(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
>         switch (event.info.code) {
>            case "SharedObject.Flush.Success":
>            break;
>            case "SharedObject.Flush.Failed":
>            break;
>        }
>
>        _so.removeEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onFlushStatus);
>    }
> ```
>
> }
>   }

The Value `_co` will always be your reference to this object, renaming it will create a new instance. I have taken these files apart and they are well written XML files that accommodate to AMF For Servers. In this example "Saving", "Clearing", and "Flushing Methods" are described in simple detail.